# Best way to have have a live copy of a SQL server database for read-access

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 that houses a critical database for an enterprise application. There are also many other read-only apps that do read-only queries and I want these to hit a copy of the main database so it does not affect operations on the main database.

What is the best way to archive this? (Mirror, Log-Shipping, etc...)

Other notes

- A latency of a few minutes on the second server would be fine.
- There is about 7 applications that do short to long read-only queries.
- Second database can be on a second server.
- Having the ability to use the secondary database as a disaster backup might be nice.
- The queries from these applications can happen at any time (they are not scheduled)
- The main application would access the primary database (read/write)
- Upgrading to SQL Server 2012/2014 is not an option at this time.
- Would like to keep the performance hit to the primary server down if possible

Comment: Does *log shipping* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187103(v=sql.105).aspx) meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for the link Pieter. That looks like the best option. Back in February we decided to just have the app hit the live database with a read-only user.  If I recall, I did not want to do log shipping because I was not sure when we were going to upgrade 2012 and I guess upgrading a log-shipping is more complicated.